# the issue convert buffer to hex string in c

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I'm trying to convert buffer to hex string in c as the below,
the below image is the input file
[image]
it's a binary file.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#include "string.h"
#include "fcntl.h"


#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <BaseTsd.h>
typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t;
#endif

#define  BUFF_SIZE   5     

int main()
{
    char     buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int      fd;
    ssize_t  rd_size;
    FILE *rfp;
    FILE *ofp;
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    rfp = fopen("test.bin", "rb");


         while ( 4== (fread(buff, 1, 4, rfp)))
        {
            fprintf(ofp, "%02X%02X%02X%02X \n", buff[0], buff[1], buff[2], buff[3]);
        }
    
    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(rfp);
    return 0;
}
```

then I use above code, I've got bin to hex file
but I've got the problem at result.

```
04002B2B 
000001FFFFFFFF 
00030003 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00000300 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00000000 
00500050 
00500050 
00500050 
00500050 
00000000 
FFFFFF80002000 
00000000 
08700F00 
00000000 
00000000 
00000001 
00000002 
00000003 
00000004 
00000005 
00000006 
00000007 
FFFFFF800FFFFFFFF01E 
087007FFFFFF80 
00320032 
0BFFFFFFB80820 
00050005 
2DFFFFFFC7114D 
00FFFFFFC20118 
00001B58
```

As you can see that the above file,     especially I don't want to "000001FFFFFFFF " this output. But I don't know what am I supposed to do

## update

I want to run in the linux. but if I make a execute file, I got the segmant error.
Can you let me know what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem here is that your `char` type seems to be `signed` (if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` is implementation specific). That means that values larger equal or larger than `0x80` will be treated as negative values (with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) systems).

And when you pass such a value to `printf` and the value is [promoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int` it is sign-extended. So `0xff` becomes `0xffffffff`, which is then printed.

If you use `unsigned char` for your values instead, then values like `0xff` are not extended when being promoted to `unsigned int`. So `0xff` is promoted to `0x000000ff`, and the leading zeroes are not printed.

---

Another issue is that you are using the wrong format for `printf`. The format `"%x"` is for `unsigned int` and not `unsigned char`. If you read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see a big table with all the formatting code and the different size prefixes for different types. To print an `unsigned char` you should use the `hh` prefix, as in `"%hhx"`.

Comment: quick question. I want to run in the linux with gcc but I have got some segmant fault,

Comment: @grander3 That is another problem entirely, and something you should post a new question about. But before you do that, please use a debugger to find out *where* the crash happens. In the source you show, indicate the location of the crash with a comment. Also show the values of all involved variables at the point of the crash. Oh, and when you catch the crash, be sure to walk up the callstack to *your* code.

Comment: @grander3 Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That will help you here on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: There is no error when I compile with gcc, but when I run the execute file, there is a segment error happen

Comment: @grander3 I understand, and you need to learn how to use a debugger to find out where in the code the crash happens. You might want to find [a gdb tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) to help you with that (search for `gdb tutorial` for more alternatives).

Comment: @grander3 Oh, and remember that `fopen` can *fail* and will then return a null pointer. You should not dereference or otherwise use null pointers, except to test if they are null.